# Can "Welcome to SFSE" pre-canned response be added to the First Post Queue "Share Feedback" option?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, review-queue

I spent a little time this morning in the moderation queues; something I haven't done in a while.  While in the Low Quality Posts queue, I believe there was an option to include a pre-canned welcome comment like the following:

> Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example would be helpful.

But when reviewing he First Post Queue, which has a "Share Feedback" option, this is not among the prepared choices, only "Question is unclear" and "Question is too broad" are available.  Could we add this welcome message to the First Post queue feedback options as well?